# Why won't the image go over in this code?

Tags: html, css

I'll show you the chords I made

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>프로토타입</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;   
        }

        .event_slide input[id*=slide]{
            display: none;
        }
        .event_slide .slidewrap{
            max-width: 1200px ;
            margin:0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .event_slide .slidelist{
            white-space:nowrap;
            font-size: 0; 
        }
        .event_slide .slidelist > li {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 100%;
            transition:all .5s;
        }
        .event_slide .slidelist > li > a {
            display:block;
            position:relative;
        }
        .event_slide .slidelist > li > a img {
            width: 100%;
        } 
        .event_slide .slidelist label {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10;
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            padding: 50px;
            cursor: pointer; 
        }   
        .event_slide .slidelist .left {
            left: 30px;
            background: url(images/index/header02/slide/left.png) center center / 100% no-repeat;
        }
        .event_slide .slidelist .right {
            right : 30px;
            background: url(images/index/header02/slide/right.png) center center / 100% no-repeat;
        }
        .event_slide [id="slide01"]:checked ~ .slidewrap .slidelist > li {transform: :translateX(0%);
        }
        .event_slide [id="slide02"]:checked ~ .slidewrap .slidelist > li {transform: :translateX(-100%);
        }
        .event_slide [id="slide03"]:checked ~ .slidewrap .slidelist > li {transform: :translateX(-200%);
        }
        .event_slide [id="slide04"]:checked ~ .slidewrap .slidelist > li {transform: :translateX(-300%);
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="event_slide">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide01" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide02">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide03">
        <input type="radio" name="slide" id="slide04">
    <div class="slidewrap">
        <ul class="slidelist">
            <li>
                <a>
                    <label for="slide04" class="left"></label>
                    <img src="images/index/header02/slide/slide01.png">
                    <label for="slide02" class="right"></label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <label for="slide01" class="left"></label>
                    <img src="images/index/header02/slide/slide02.png">
                    <label for="slide03" class="right"></label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <label for="slide02" class="left"></label>
                    <img src="images/index/header02/slide/slide03.png">
                    <label for="slide04" class="right"></label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a>
                    <label for="slide03" class="left"></label>
                    <img src="images/index/header02/slide/slide04.png">
                    <label for="slide01" class="right"></label>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--slidewrap end-->
    </div><!--event_slide end-->
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't write javascript, I just wanted to write a code that goes over the image when I press the arrow with CSS only.
But in style

```css
.event_slide .slidelist .right {
right : 30px;
background: url(images/index/header02/slide/right.png) center center / 100% no-repeat;
subsequent
.event_slide [id="slide01"]:checked ~ .slidewrap .slidelist > li {transform: :translateX(0%);
}
.event_slide [id="slide02"]:checked ~ .slidewrap .slidelist > li {transform: :translateX(-100%);
}
.event_slide [id="slide03"]:checked ~ .slidewrap .slidelist > li {transform: :translateX(-200%);
}
.event_slide [id="slide04"]:checked ~ .slidewrap .slidelist > li {transform: :translateX(-300%);
}
```

The image does not pass because is not applied.
What should I fix?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00dI1.png)

I wanted the image to slide by pressing the arrows on both sides

Comment: Please check the syntax of your CSS. There is at least one error - a spurious : in a transform. And in the code posted as part of the text (please post this as code to make it more readable) there is a missing  }. Making your code into a runnable snippet would also help us see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have now tried your code with the syntax errors (there were 4 occrrences of transform: :translateX) corrected and the slides move when clicking the arrows. Voting to close as its really just a typo. If you have further problems please create a new question and include a runnable snippet.